# custom scrollbar(horizontal) within custom scrollbar(vertical)

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

i want horizontal scroll bar within vertical scroll bar, i tried it by modifying it class base,  but it's not working properly, is it possible?

in short we want example2 within example1 from this [demo tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to convert this id "scrollbar1" to class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
    });
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
    });
```

then you can use it multiple time. hope you can help from this